# jQuery closest exclude self

Tags: jquery

`closest()` will get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree. But I want to know if there is any way to get the result excluding itself (I mean just get the parents of it).

Let me take a example. Please review it.

```
<div id='div1' class="container">
    <div id="div2" class="container">
        <!--many nested div.container as it directly or indirectly children -->
    </div>
    <div id="div3" class="container">
        <!--many nested div.container as it directly or indirectly children -->
    </div>
</div>

$(function() {

    $('div.container').on('mouseover', function(e){
        //I only want to select the first parent with the class container.
        //closest include the this element. 
        console.log($(this).closest('.container').attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Comment: can explain more? adding code snippets would be more helpful...

Comment: `.parents()` will help.

Comment: @Reigel Could you please review it again? I had updated. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right answer is `.parents('.container:first');` thanks

Comment: Performance-wise, `.parent().closest('.container')` should perform better as it stops after matching the first element, unlike `.parents()` which always traverse all the way up to document level.

Comment: Well yes. Moving one level up when you don't want to match the first level is only logical. Either way both have the same output - the difference is that having `:first` inside a `parents()` may be a little costly as `:first` is a Sizzle extension and selectors are usually matched against each (ancestor) element before returning.

Answer (score 117):

You can traverse a level up before trying to find the `.closest()` ancestor:

```
$(this).parent().closest('.container');
```

Answer (score 3):

Vanilla js:

```
el.parentElement.closest('.container')
```

Jquery:

```
el.parent().closest('.container');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want only parent divs, then yes $(this).parents('.container') would work. If you want to look for the closest element and allow for it to be a sibling (which it seems might be what you are actually trying to accomplish) you can use $(this).prev('.container').

Comment: This won't be useful because you never know if its parent is one level up or higher and you targeting its parents by class!
What if <div id="div2" class="container"></div> was nested in another div tag that had no class and he still wanted to target it parents!

Answer (score 0):

That's because [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) works by *"by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree."*.  Instead, call [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to move up one level and start there.

Here's a little helper function you can add to your projet for easy re-use:

```js
// get the first element that matches the selector, excluding itself
$.fn.closestParent = function(selector) {
    return this.parent().closest(selector)
}
```

And then use like this:

```js
$(".js-start-here").closestParent("div")
```

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```js
// get the first element that matches the selector, excluding itself
$.fn.closestParent = function(selector) {
    return this.parent().closest(selector)
}

$(".js-start-here").closestParent("div").css({color: "red"})
```

```css
div {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  Level 1
  <div>
    Level 2 - Match
    <div class="js-start-here">
      Level 3 - Start
      <div>
        Level 4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```