# Find closest outermost nav (multiple nested nav elements)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider the following HTML

```
...
<section>
    <nav> <!-- I need this one -->
        <section>
            <nav>
                <span></span>
            </nav>
        </section>
    </nav>
</section>
...
```

Now I have a reference to the `span` and I want to find the outermost nav element. Now, this code doesn't return the correct `nav`

```
let span = $('span'),
    nav  = span.closest('nav').closest('nav');
```

`nav` is still the parent of the `span` because `$('nav').closest('nav') will return itself (which I think is just weird). So the question is how this can be done ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery closest exclude self](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628889/jquery-closest-exclude-self)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the outermost element, use:

```
span.parents('nav').last()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `span.parents('nav').last()`